# Unable to set string to Int in modelDreiven interceptor in struts2

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, ognl, model-driven

hi  Here is my problem

I have `select` tag in my jsp

```
  <select list="#{'1':cat,'2':'dog','3':Monkey}" name="animalId" />
```

In my action class I am using `modelDriven` Interceptor some thing like below

```
 public class ActionClass extends AcionSuport implements ModelDriven<BeanClass>
  {

     BeanClass modelName = new BeanClass();
     public BeanClass getModel()
     {

        return modelName;
        }
     }
```

Here is my bean class

```
   public class BeanClass
  {
    private Integer animalId;
       //There is getters and setters for animalId;

       }
```

What my problem is .. When I want to get the data of dropdown box in my action class its giving me `null` value.

```
Ofcourse I am using `modelDriven` interceptor in my `struts.xml`
```

But when I convert `animalId` into `String` type in `BeanClass` its working fine.

As per the documentation.. Type casting has to be done automatically ... But I cant get any error in console aslo...

Plesae some one help me..

Comment: And why do you use modeldriven?

Comment: Cause i wll have fields which are more than 30  and more I cant create getters and setters for every action class. So I will use singel bean class .. And That too its felxible to use data in objects form ..

Comment: You can use *single bean class* w/o modeldriven.

Comment: Exactly. And btw, your question is full of errors: missing quotes on cat and monkey, typo on ActionSuport, missing setter for the bean model... :/

Comment: @AndreaLigios may be typo You can ignore them.. But i cant remove modelDriven Interface now As I have done to many actions for that same action class ...

Comment: Don't create new instance of your `BeanClass`. Check that correct numbers are being submitted. Try with `dev` mode enabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The field type in your model should correspond to the key type in the drop-down and the value type if you want to preselect an option in the value attribute. If the key and a value has the same type of object it can compare with each other. If you have a key of type string or char and the corresponding value of type `Integer` then OGNL will try to get/set the property of the same type as a key. In your case you instantiate a map using OGNL with the string/char key type. That's why your property isn't set and it's set if your property type is `String`. You can change the drop-down in the way that it creates `Integer` keys and `String` values.

```
<select list="#{1:'cat',2:'dog',3:'Monkey'}" name="animalId" />
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but that did not worked. If I am not mistaken as per the documentation struts wil do type casting cause HTTP will give you everything in string format... Even If I create key value as Intteger in dropdown .. HTTP will return that key as String if I am not mistaken.. Please help where  i am missing

Comment: The string in OGNL enclosed in quotas, other HTTP strings are converted to a corresponding type.

Comment: so how to get the value then.. Please help

Comment: set `devMode` to `true` and post errors warnings you have.